# angular2 base url and relative paths on gh-pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my project site on gh-pages, it's angular2 app with webpack, I set the base url to my repo name and everything loads fine except the relative paths in the templates, here is what I mean

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  template: `
      <img class="fb-logo" [src]="fbLogo"/>
      <img class="ang-logo" [src]="angularLogo"/>
  `
})

export class Header{

    angularLogo = '../../assets/img/angular-logo.png';
    fbLogo = '../../assets/img/share/facebook.svg';
}
```

This works well on local dev, but when I push it to `gh-pages` branch It gives 404 because it's trying to get it from the root server `http://myAcc.github.io/assets/img/fbLogo.svg` instead of `http://myAcc.github.io/myRepo/assets/img/fbLogo.svg`

I couldn't figure out how to fix it so I tried to use it as inline-svg using `require`

```
angularLogo = require('../../assets/img/angular-logo.png');
fbLogo = require('../../assets/img/share/facebook.svg');
```

it works fine on local (with xss warnings) but when I deploy it to `gh-pages` It refuses to run over https.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your dev and your gh-pages have different roots levels, your dev root url must be something like this: `http://localhost:port` while your gh-page root is `http://myAcc.github.io` that's why your relative icons are not working.

I guess that you have different webpack configs, change your production config to something like this:

```
output: {
  path: 'something',
  filename: 'something.bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/myRepo/' // this will add /myRepo/ to all your assets
}
```

Here's a quick explanation about publicPath:

> **output.publicPath**
>
> The `publicPath` specifies the public URL address of the output files
>   when referenced in a browser. For loaders that embed `<script>` or
>   `<link>` tags or reference assets like images, `publicPath` is used as the
>   `href` or `url()` to the file when it's different than their location on
>   disk (as specified by `path`). This can be helpful when you want to host
>   some or all output files on a different domain or on a CDN. The
>   Webpack Dev Server also uses this to determine the `path` where the
>   output files are expected to be served from. As with `path` you can use
>   the `[hash]` substitution for a better caching profile.

You can find more info about `publicPath` [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#outputpublicpath)

### Update:

The `output.publicPath`only works with assets that were already declared since you are specifying your img source dynamically it won't work. You can use file-loader to do that for you, just change your loader to this:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
  loader: 'file?name=/myRepo/[name].[ext]'
},
```

So whenever you require a `jpg|png|gif` on your code it adds the string `/myRepo/`.

Another solution is creating your custom `pipe`, since you are using the angular2-webpack-starter your building process exports your environment to the varaible `ENV` so you can use that for your custom pipe, something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'pathResolver'})
export class PathResolverPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(path: string): string {

    return ENV === 'production' ? path.replace(/assets/i, 'myRepo/assets') : path;
  }
}
```

And use it on your component like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { PathResolverPipe } from 'path/to/pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  pipes: [PathResolverPipe],
  template: `
      <img class="fb-logo" [src]="fbLogo | pathResolver"/>
      <img class="ang-logo" [src]="angularLogo | pathResolver"/>
  `
})

export class Header{

    angularLogo = '../../assets/img/angular-logo.png';
    fbLogo = '../../assets/img/share/facebook.svg';
}
```

Comment: I added `publicPath` but didn't effect, It still requests the url from the root, I'm using https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't have a webpack.config file, and neither do I want to implement a pipe. Angular-cli created an envrionment.prod.ts file - any idea what I put in that to setup base.url properly?

Answer (score 5):

For future visitors, github pages deploy has been removed from ng-cli and will be available as different npm, 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4385

But it looks like deploying an angular app to github pages is now more effortless with https://github.com/angular-buch/angular-cli-ghpages

Usage:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
angular-cli-ghpages [OPTIONS]
```

there is also a shorter ngh command available

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
ngh [OPTIONS]
```