# github pages, Angular2, vendor.build not found

Tags: git, angular, github-pages

My trouble(Günter Zöchbauer give me a solution [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser), but i'm not sure. It related to routing in application, my trouble - part of application resources not found. If i'm wrong - please explain where):
I have Angular2 application. It works on local machine without troubles.

Build (

```
- assets folder
- index.html
- main.[some_hash].bundle.js
- vendor.[same_hash].bundle.js
- polyfills.[same_hash].bundle.js
- .map(3 items)
- .gz(3 items)
- .map.gz(3 items)
```

) has been uploaded to gh-pages branch correct. 
But if you trying open published app in browser, *vendor.bundle* returns 404(*main.bundle* and *polyfills.bundle* - OK, 200).

When i created(directly via github interface) manually file **some_name.[same_hash].js** with code from vendor.bundle (for example **some_name** === 'vendo') and add it to *index.html* instead *vendor* - application works fine. Created manually *vendor.[hash].js* - 404 again.

This problem is not appeared immediately, after publishing. Some time all worked, but few days ago - it happend

Actually i have 2 repos with this problem and 4, where vendor.[..].js worked fine.

Comment: You can't use `PathLocationStrategy` on gh-pages.

Comment: I guess you are wrong at "but i'm not sure. It related to routing" ;-) Have you tried to switch to `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: It could also be `<base href="...">`.

Comment: Yes. You've been right. It related. After experiments with `HashLocationStrategy` or/and `base href` i was received 3 404th(for each `.js`) or 6(for `.js` and `.css` files) :)

Comment: I solve this via ugly patch(changing name in webpack.config of 'vendor' -> 'vndr' for final bundle)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Comment: For future visitors, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43274956/1896608