# Angular2, Angular-cli, Webpack - image assets not loading on github:pages after prod deploy

Tags: angular, webpack, github-pages, angular-cli

---

This is NOT a duplicate question:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051959/angular2-base-url-and-relative-paths-on-gh-pages) explains the problem but that project was not built with angular-cli, as mine is, hence I do not have a `webpack.config` file.

Whilst the issue I describe below is clearly about getting the base_url setting correct, it is not the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516651/set-base-url-for-angular-2-http-requests), which is about setting up angular to send requests to a base_url like an api.

---

My project builds and runs on localhost and also on `github:pages` (even the css all loads correctly). The only thing which does not work on github:pages are the images, which all return 404s (even though I can see them if I navigate to the assets folder directly in the browser).

The problem is that on localhost, angular-cli runs the project with no subfolder after the hostname. But on `github:pages` it does.

Say for example the project name is `testapp` then on `github:pages` it is deployed here:

```
https://<username>.github.io/testapp
```

The images are in

```
src/assets/images
```

They are referenced in css inside angular-2 component using relative paths like this:

```
background-image: url('../../assets/images/dining-room.png');
```

So how do I configure angular-2 production deployment file so that in production the path becomes:

```
background-image: url('testapp/assets/dining-room.png');
```

I understand that `github:pages` is based off Jekyll and I understand [this explanation](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/), but what I don't understand is how do you configure an angular-cli project to be aware that `github:pages` is using a folder to deploy the app.

---

**UPDATE 1**

So far I have figured out that the command line for deploying to `github:pages` has a base_href option. So I can do this:

```
ng github-pages:deploy --base-href /testapp/
```

I can then see in the /dist folder that the html file has been changed to include the base href, like this:

```
<base href="/testapp/">
```

I would have expected this to fix the problem automatically, but the images still return a 404. This base_href is not being automatically injected into the relative paths, as you would expect. Locally the index.html file has `<base href="/">` and obviously that works.

---

**UPDATE 2**

In trying to solve this I am coming to believe this is related to the way Angular builds components. A very good explanation of that can be found [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html).

---

**EDIT added angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "name": "floorbook"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "fb",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post your angular-cli.json ?

Comment: angular-cli.json now added

Comment: and the down vote is because....someone didn't get a visit from Santa Claus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Understanding that ALL components in Angular2 are declared as relative paths was the key to solving this. Simply put this means when ng is building/compiling your project, everything is relative to ROOT. See the link UPDATE 2 in the question.

So, my CSS files is local to the component and 2 folders deep in my `app/src` hierarchy. This is why I was referencing images like so:

```
../../assets/images/<file>.png
```

But when angular builds `/assets/images` is at ROOT - you can see that in the `DIST` folder after building (i.e. after running `ng github-pages:deploy`)

So all I needed to do was change the css to reference directly from root (ie. ignore that this css file is 2 folders deep in a component):

```
assets/images/<file>.png
```

Then build with:

```
ng github-pages:deploy --base-href /testapp/
```

In production, those images links will then work since `/testapp/` is now the root, and they are relative to root, hence:

```
/testapp/assets/images/<file>.png
```

---

**Answer to what I thought was the problem - how to access APP_BASE_HREF from inside a component**

For future reference, others coming to this question might be thinking as I was and that access is needed to `base-href` directly in the component to solve this problem. Since I figured out how to do that, I thought I would add it here:

1 - In your `app.module.ts` you need to import it and provide it:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/your-value/'}]
```

**WARNING** - note that this is now hard coding your production base-href. This overrides whatever you have set in `index.html` (so using the `ng build` command line option will be pointless, as that is what creates that setting in the `index.html` inside the `DIST` folder).

2 - In your component add 2 imports and inject `APP_BASE_REF` in the constructor:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref:string) { 
  console.log(this.baseHref);
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

If in step 1 above if you set your value to:

```
useValue : '/'
```

and then deploy to github:pages...after you browse to your app, it will stop using the folder name (it simply disappears from the address bar after the app loads...although the app will continue to function).

**AND FINALLY**

As of Dec 30 2016 it is not possible to have images inside the component and reference them using local relative paths. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747680/using-angular-cli-and-unable-to-use-relative-image-paths-in-css-files) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6637).

Comment: Hi there! I think I'm having the same problem as you.. I have an Angular app hosted on a server. The url address is something like someserver.com/myApp. So when I access to the website I can't see the image assets because the browser tries to look for them inside someserver.com/assets/.. Locally, I just set an img url like: url('assets/Images/image.png') and it works fine. How would you solve it according to your explanation ??

Comment: @Gerardo See the two links at the end of my answer

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue on localhost in dev mode. Whenever I would make an update to the SCSS file, my background images would not display in the browser. My background images were all referencing relative paths like:
`background: url(../../assets/heros/contact-hero-mbl@2x.jpg);`. I updated the image paths to:
`background: url(/assets/heros/contact-hero-mbl@2x.jpg);` and everything seems to be working as expected. Hope this helps someone.