# Angular2: Cannot load assets folder images

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have created a project from angular CLI, placed an image under assets folder.
It works fine in localhost environment, but when deployed to github pages it's throwing 404.

[image]

[image]

After `build --prod --base-href "my-project"`

Base href is changed in index.html of dist directory.

```
 <base href="my-project">
```

After deploying to github page it couldn't find the image.

```
GET https://srk.github.io/assets/srk-favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

I guess the URL should be `https://srk.github.io/my-project/assets/srk-favicon.ico`

Comment: You aren't actually asking a question... You're just stating facts

Comment: i think the path is wrong. in my project i have placed like ../app/assets/demo.png app the main folder. so place the src link from main folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 base url and relative paths on gh-pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051959/angular2-base-url-and-relative-paths-on-gh-pages)

Answer (score 5):

You have to make base `href` change to below.

```
<base href="/my-project">
```

And then change `img` src to below

```
<img src="assets/srk-favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Why we need to do this ?

Comment: @Lijo thanks for heads up.. What would be alternative to this then? I know this works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
src="./assets/srk-favicon.ico"
```

Instead of :

```
src="../assets/srk-favicon.ico"
```